# How can I automatically size my title to fit within my margins

Tags: fonts

I am writing my thesis presentation page. My title is mildly long and already fits into one line. I was wondering if there is a way to automatically size the font (and bold it) so the title reaches maximum size and still is in one line?

Thank you!

Comment: So: if the title were but two words, it would still stretch to fit the line? And if it were 50 words, it would shrink to fill but one line?

Comment: \resizebox from the graphicx package is the usual choice (just use .99\textwidth to handle roundoff).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that you really want this but the `graphicx` package and

```
\begin{center}
\bfseries
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{My Title}
\end{center}
```

will stretch the text out and add some vertical space.